# O que é SQL dinâmico?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, oracle

Já observei muitos casos em que alguns mostram como usar, e outros em que simplesmente desaconselham o uso de *SQL dinâmico*.
Me surgiram as seguintes dúvidas:

1. Mas enfim, quando devemos ou não usar o SQL dinâmico?
2. Quais os cuidados que devemos ter ao usar?
3. Quais as restrições?
4. E quais as alternativas?

*Exemplo: imagine uma aplicação que chame a seguinte `procedure`.*

```
create proc teste
@NomeColuna varchar(50),
@nomeTabel varchar(50),
@NomeColunafiltro varchar(50)
@filtro varchar(50)
as

select @NomeColuna 
  from @nomeTabel
 where @NomeColunafiltro = @filtro
```

Onde a consulta da `query` é totalmente (ou parcialmente) montada através dos parâmetros.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1.Mas em fim quando devemos ou não usar SQL dinâmico ?**

Pois bem, nem sempre devemos preferir o que é
dinâmico ao que é estático por vários
motivos. No que diz respeito aos bancos de dados, sempre que possível
devemos utilizar instruções estáticas. As
instruções estáticas são aquelas que
normalmente programamos em uma aplicação e que serão
encaminhadas para o banco de dados por um método de acesso.
Elas podem ser estáticas para o banco de dados e serem
montadas dinamicamente na aplicação.

**Quando usar :**

> 1º SQL dinâmico é útil quando você estiver substituindo partes de uma consulta que não pode ser substituído por outros métodos.
>
> 2º SQL cujo texto é desconhecido em tempo de compilação.
>
> 3º SQL que não é suportado como SQL estática.

**Quando não usar :**

> 1º Por segurança,o SQL dinâmico é propício a ocorrer riscos caso você não souber lidar com ele corretamente.
>
> 2º O cache e otimização de plano usando parametrização aplicadas para ajudar a lidar com recompilações constantes.
>
> 3º Compilação bem-sucedida cria dependências de objeto de esquema.

**Um exemplo de SQL dinâmico :**

Comando sql não dinâmico :

```
var command = new SqlCommand("select * from myTable where id = @someId");
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@someId", idValue));
```

Comando sql dinâmico :

```
var command = new SqlCommand("select * from myTable where id = " + idValue);
```

**2.Quais os cuidados que devemos ter ao usar ?**

Você precisa ter muito cuidado com o SQL dinâmico.Um SQL muito dinâmico pode arrastar para baixo o desempenho do SQL Server porque ele não pode armazenar detalhes de otimização ou planos de execução de SQL gerado dinamicamente. Podem ocorrer problemas de bloqueio também.

Se desejarmos fazer alguma manipulação
nos dados retornados por uma execução dinâmica,
devemos fazer uso de uma tabela temporária que será
preenchida com o retorno da execução. Esta tabela
temporária vai armazenar o último resultado da(s)
instrução(es) dinâmica(s) e deve conter a
mesma quantidade e tipos de dados das colunas que o resultado.

As instruções dinâmicas
são executadas no contexto do banco de dados em atual e,
se dentro da instrução dinâmica o contexto
de banco de dados for modificado, ele somente é válido
durante a execução dinâmica.

**3. Quais as restrições ?**

Uma pergunta comum entre os usuários do SQL dinâmico,é de por que o seguinte código não funciona :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc @tablename sysname AS
   SELECT * FROM @tablename
```

Quando você começa a passar os nomes de tabelas e colunas como parâmetros, você definitivamente está a perder o controle.

Se você quiser fazer o descrito acima (exceto o fato de que SELECT * não deve ser usado no código de produção), para reduzir a digitação, você está no caminho errado. É muito melhor para escrever dez ou vinte procedimentos armazenados, mesmo se eles são semelhantes uns aos outros.

```
UPDATE tbl SET @colname = @value WHERE keycol = @keyval
```

Neste caso, as pessoas querem atualizar uma coluna que quer  seleccionar em tempo de execução. A descrição acima é realmente legal em T-SQL, mas o que acontece é simplesmente que a variável @colname é atribuído ao valor em @value para cada linha afetada na tabela.

Neste caso,SQL dinâmico iria pedir para o usuário ter permissões de UPDATE na tabela,algo que não é bom. Portanto, há toda razão para evitá-lo. Aqui é uma solução bastante simples:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    col1 = CASE @colname WHEN 'col1' THEN @value ELSE col1 END,
       col2 = CASE @colname WHEN 'col2' THEN @value ELSE col2 END,
       ...
```

Outro erro que as pessoas tem em comum é quererem acessar outro banco de dados através da seguinte forma no SQL dinâmico :

```
SELECT * FROM @dbname + '..tbl'
```

Neste caso, a tabela está em outro banco de dados,que é de alguma forma determinada de forma dinâmica. Parece haver várias razões pelas quais as pessoas querem fazer isso, e dependendo da sua razão subjacente, a solução é diferente.

Outro erro comum é de que as pessoas criam tabelas com colunas desconhecidas :

```
CREATE TABLE with Unknown Columns
```

Às vezes eu vejo pessoas quebrando a cabeça para entender porque eles criam uma tabela temporária no SQL dinâmico, e então eles não podem acessá-la, porque ela desapareceu quando o SQL dinâmico saiu. O que é necessário fazer é criar a tabela fora do SQL dinâmico.

Uma solução é criar uma tabela temporária global, um com duas # no nome,para instância de ##. Essa tabela é visível para todos os processos (de modo que você pode ter que tomar precauções para tornar o nome único), e a menos que você deixe ela explicitamente, ela existe até suas saídas do processo.

**4.Quais as alternativas ?**

Eu vejo muitas pessoas reclamando de que o SQL dinâmico não é seguro,e ele pode não ser seguro mesmo caso você não souber lidar com ele de forma correta,por causa de SQL Injection é muito perigoso você lidar com dados importantes caso não tiver conhecimento com o SQL dinâmico.

**Exemplo de SQL Injection :**

```
DROP TABLE secret_records;
CREATE TABLE secret_records (
  user_name    VARCHAR2(9),
  service_type VARCHAR2(12),
  value        VARCHAR2(30),
  date_created DATE
);

INSERT INTO secret_records (
  user_name, service_type, value, date_created
)
VALUES ('Andy', 'Waiter', 'Serve dinner at Cafe Pete', SYSDATE);
 
INSERT INTO secret_records (
  user_name, service_type, value, date_created
)
VALUES ('Chuck', 'Merger', 'Buy company XYZ', SYSDATE);
```

Há algumas alternativas para SQL dinâmico,algumas delas são :

**sp_executesql**

É uma maneira mais limpa para evitar concatenando o nome do banco de dados para cada objeto referenciado na declaração.

```
USE TOOLS;
GO
 
ALTER PROCEDURE getTableNames @db_name sysname
AS
BEGIN
 
    -- use a @sql variable to store the whole query
    -- without concatenating the database name
 
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
 
    SET @sql = 'SELECT name FROM sys.tables';
 
    -- concatenate the database name to the
    -- sp_executesql call, just once
 
    DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
 
    SET @cmd = 'EXEC '+ QUOTENAME(@db_name) +'.sys.sp_executesql @sql';
 
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@sql nvarchar(max)', @sql
 
END
GO


 
EXEC getTableNames 'msdb';
```

**PROS :** O SQL dinâmico é tomado como um todo e não precisa ser criado várias concatenações.

**CONS :** Precisa de um pouco mais de trabalho do que uma concatenação em linha reta e pode ser visto como "obscuro".Sofre dos mesmos problemas encontrados com o SQL dinâmico,porque a instrução é, novamente, tratado como uma string.

**System object**

Agradável e fácil: cada procedimento armazenado que você criar no banco de dados principal com o prefixo "sp_" pode ser executado a partir de qualquer contexto de banco de dados.

```
USE master;
GO
 
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_getTableNames
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT name FROM sys.tables
END
GO
 
EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject 'sp_getTableNames'
GO
 
USE msdb;
GO
 
EXEC sp_getTableNames;
```

**PROS :** Não há necessidade de usar o SQL dinâmico.

**CONS :** Requer a criação de objetos no banco de dados "master", que é algo que é melhor evitar.Funciona somente com stored procedure.

Creio que isto já deu para tirar algumas de suas dúvidas,mas caso ainda tenha mais,aconselho você a olhar as seguintes documentações [aqui](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#unknowncolumns) e [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm).